# Sou iniciante em C, preciso de ajuda em uma tarefa!

Tags: c

O enunciado diz: 1. Sabendo que uma empresa possui 20 funcionários, faça um programa que leia o salário e o sexo de cada funcionário e informe quantos funcionários ganham mais de R$ 1.000,00 e quantas mulheres ganham acima de R$ 5.000,00. Informe ainda o menor e o maior salário e a média de salário entre os homens e entre as mulheres.

Por enquanto fiz o seguinte:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)

{
    int quant_mais1000,quant_H,quant_M,mulher_mais5000,soma_H,soma_M;
    float salario,menor,maior,mediaH,mediaM;
    char sexo;

    for(int i=1;i<=20;i++){

        printf("Insira o salario: ");
        scanf("%f",&salario);

        printf("Insira o sexo: ");      
        scanf("\n%c",&sexo);

        if(i=1){
            maior=salario;
            menor=salario;
        }

        if (salario>=100){
            quant_mais1000++;
        }

        if(sexo == 'M' || sexo == 'm'){

            soma_H=soma_H+salario;
            quant_H++;          
        }


        if(sexo == 'F' || sexo == 'f'){

            soma_M=soma_M+salario;
            quant_M++;

            if (salario>=5000){
                mulher_mais5000++;
            }

        }

        if(salario>maior){
            maior=salario;
        }

        if(salario<maior){
            menor=salario;
        }
    }

    printf("Salario acima de R$ 1000,00 e: %d",quant_mais1000);

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

---

Porém o programa não pára quando chega aos 20 que é a quantidade de funcionários. Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if(i=1){
        maior=salario;
        menor=salario;
    }
```

Quando você coloca em uma condição i = 1, toda vez que seu código chegar nela, ela ira atribuir o valor 1 no i, ou seja, seu `for` nunca saira do 1, o correto seria `if (i == 1)`

E pelo seu programa você deveria apagar isso, pois não faz sentido, você ja colocou la embaixo as condições que definem o menor e maior salario.

Comment: Opa, é verdade!
Acabei esquecendo desse detalhe, muito obrigado!